# pass values from mssql to views in node

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, express

Being fairly new to Node js and javascript itself . i have been trying to find a solution to my problem .

This is my app.js file

```
var express=require ('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require ('path');
var sql = require('mssql');

var app = express();

const config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'localhost\\SQLEXPRESS', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance 
    database: 'pcgdb',

    options: {
        encrypt: false // Use this if you're on Windows Azure 
            }
    };

const request = new sql.Request()

//view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
   res.render('index')
});

app.get('/new_project', function(req, res) {
    function(data,err){
       var data= request.query('select Project_Type_Desc from Project_Type');
       //not sure what should go here !!

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log ('server listening on port 3000')
})
```

my problem : i am trying to query the database(Ms SQL SERVER) which has a project type table with Project_Type_Description column. and pass it to my view to serve as values to a dropdown . I have 10 other tables i have to query from as values to 10 other dropdowns (please clue me as to how to accomplish this ). the view i am trying to pass to is the /new_project. The way i try is not working , Please help .

thanks

Comment: How is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

Return a response.

```
app.get('/new_project', function(req, res) {
 function(data,err){
   var data= request.query('select Project_Type_Desc from 
                           Project_Type');
   return res.status(200).send(data);
 }
});
```